# Hierarchial clustering in R

Tags: r

I am getting the following  error when I use hclust function? How can I solve this problem? 
I am using windows 7 and 2.12.3 version of R.

```
n_seq <- 250                                                   
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=n_seq, nrow=n_seq)    
for (idx in 1:n_seq) 
{mat[idx,idx] <- 0.0}         
for(idx in 1:(n_seq-1) )
{intemp <- read.xls("C:// clustal.xls", sheet = idx ); 
mat[(1+idx):n_seq,idx] <- intemp[1:(n_seq-idx), 11]}

fit <- hclust(as.dist(mat), method="single")

Error in hclust(as.dist(mat), method = "single") : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example (see this post for tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: As nullglob said. BTW, read again the answer(s) on the link nullglob gave you. It is impossible to run your code, so that is _not_ a reproducible example.

Comment: for more debugging: try using `cat` to print out the index numbers as you go through, so you can easily tell which sheet is giving you the problem; then use `which(!is.finite(mat),arr.ind=TRUE)` to see which element(s) in the distance matrix are problematic

Answer (score 4):

This error message arises because the distance matrix `as.dist(mat)` has a bad value (`NA`, `NaN` or `Inf`) in it. If you look in the code of `hclust`, the 11th argument to the foreign function call (i.e. by compiled code) is the values of the distance matrix, and this is what R is complaining about. By default, `NA`, `NaN` or `Inf` are not accepted by foreign function calls. See `?.Fortran` for more info.